# SQLite not getting the last inserted row id in iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to get the id from the last inserted value in the SQLite table. I used the following method to achieve this. Its not getting the value.

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"INSERT INTO beacons (beacon_id, vendor_name, enter_message, enter_image, vendor_image, time_interval, received_date, uuid, major, minor) VALUES (\'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\',%d, \'%@\', \'%@\', %d, %d)",
                                   id, vendorName, sampleMessage, entryImage, thumbnail, [interval intValue], date, uuid, [majorId intValue], [minorId intValue]];

            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(_beaconDB, insert_stmt,
                               -1, &statement, NULL);
            long long lastRowId = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(_beaconDB);
            NSString *rowId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)lastRowId];
            [identity insertObject:rowId atIndex:i];
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                NSLog(@"Successfully saved");
            }
```

In the above code, the values are successfully inserted to the database table. But the unique id of the last inserted value is not returning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the last row id *after* you insert the row with `sqlite3_step`.

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO beacons (beacon_id, vendor_name, enter_message, enter_image, vendor_image, time_interval, received_date, uuid, major, minor) VALUES (\'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\',%d, \'%@\', \'%@\', %d, %d)",
                               id, vendorName, sampleMessage, entryImage, thumbnail, [interval intValue], date, uuid, [majorId intValue], [minorId intValue]];

const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
sqlite3_prepare_v2(_beaconDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
{
    NSLog(@"Successfully saved");
    long long lastRowId = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(_beaconDB);
    NSString *rowId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)lastRowId];
    [identity insertObject:rowId atIndex:i];
}
```

FYI - you also need a lot more error checking and you need to cleanup the prepared statement when you are done with it.

Comment: Thank u rmaddy.. I solved this issue by ur knowledge. But i could not understand what you are telling about the fyi

Comment: You need to check the result of `sqlite2_prepare_v2` to make sure it succeeds. And you must always finalize a prepared statement when you are done with it.

Comment: It worked but when i try to store the rowid value in array. Its not copying or storing any value in array..

Comment: Did you allocate/init the array?

Comment: Yeah!.. That helped me rmaddy. Silly mistake. Thank u